# Как сделать что бы простая виртуальная машина работала через макросы и указатель-реализация на C

Tags: c, алгоритм

Нужно сделать Vm с указателями на массив байт и чтобы были удобные макросы.Но выходят ошибка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define my_print 1
#define my_print_with_dec 2
//#define NEXTOP() *(next_instr)++
#define TARGET(op) \
case op: 
#define TARGET_NOARG(op)\
case op: 
#define DISPATCH() continue

int next_instr[5]= {my_print,my_print,my_print,0};
int opcode=0;
int oparg=0;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for(;;){

   //opcode=NEXTOP();
   opcode=*(next_instr)++;

   printf("opcode: %d",opcode);
   switch(opcode){
     TARGET(my_print) {
         printf("me-me-me!\n");
         DISPATCH();
}
 TARGET(0){
     break;
 } 


  }

    }
    return 0;
}
//<--main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
//main.cpp:39:24: error: lvalue required as increment operand
//    opcode=*(next_instr)++;
```

Comment: Ну разве ж можно применять ++ к массиву!...

Comment: Массивы - это не указатели. Их инкрементировать нельзя, нужна отдельная переменная-указатель.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил так:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define my_print 1
#define my_print_with_dec 2
#define NEXTOP() *(next_instr)++
#define TARGET(op) \
case op: 
#define TARGET_NOARG(op)\
case op: 
#define DISPATCH() continue

int mass[5]= {my_print,my_print,my_print,0};
int opcode=0;
int oparg=0;
int *next_instr;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   (next_instr)=mass; 
    for(;;){

   opcode=NEXTOP();
   printf("opcode: %d",opcode);
   switch(opcode){
     TARGET(my_print) {
         printf("me-me-me!\n");
         DISPATCH();
}
 TARGET(0){
     return 0;
 }   
  }   }
    return 0;
}
opcode: 1me-me-me!
opcode: 1me-me-me!
opcode: 1me-me-me!
opcode: 0
ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ SUCCESSFUL (общее время: 499ms)
```